# Big table with cells spanning more than one page

Tags: tables

I have a huge table that spans across multiple pages. I am using the \longtable to create these tables. Not only is the table huge, there are cells in the table that are more than one page long. For such cells, instead of continuing the content in the next page the cell fills the entire page and shows only content that fits in that page and jumps to the next row in the next page. Any help fixing this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I am posting only one cell in my table. The table itself consists of many cells like these. Hope this helps.
Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\section{Minimal Working Example}

{ \footnotesize { 
{ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{longtable}{ | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1cm} | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm} | } 
\hline
 30, 2  &    7.3071997e-09(1,0,c) + 0.050425039(2,0,c) - 0.0007346614(2,2,c) + 0.025531209(2,2,s) + 4.1082023e-10(3,0,c) + 0.05700949(4,0,c) + 2.0770709e-09(4,1,c) + 1.5124542e-09(4,1,s) - 0.028782175(4,2,c) + 0.013138827(4,2,s) + 0.10535731(4,4,c) + 0.030134448(4,4,s) - 0.021009745(6,0,c) + 0.077647547(6,2,c) - 0.045755621(6,2,s) + 9.2404255e-10(6,3,c) - 0.088258279(6,4,c) - 0.074616189(6,4,s) - 0.061815854(6,6,c) + 0.058090377(6,6,s) + 1.1485948e-08(7,0,c) + 0.026709616(8,0,c) + 0.061860038(8,2,c) - 0.11029433(8,2,s) - 9.5954232e-09(8,3,s) - 0.0068431304(8,4,c) - 0.050887506(8,4,s) + 0.075285659(8,6,c) + 0.067521705(8,6,s) + 0.070639847(8,8,c) - 0.065777628(8,8,s) - 5.2500077e-09(9,3,c) + 5.5210608e-09(9,6,c) + 5.8752925e-09(9,7,s) + 0.16024928(10,0,c) + 0.029579557(10,2,c) - 0.024436465(10,2,s) - 0.014635492(10,4,c) + 0.010115573(10,4,s) + 0.068202983(10,6,c) - 0.17353204(10,6,s) + 0.044859754(10,8,c) + 0.0029382622(10,8,s) - 0.034371315(10,10,c) + 0.032428599(10,10,s) + 0.050398873(12,0,c) + 0.042071392(12,2,c) + 0.06659721(12,2,s) + 0.031320872(12,4,c) + 0.049151718(12,4,s) - 7.2550689e-09(12,5,c) + 0.014370739(12,6,c) + 0.05026134(12,6,s) + 5.5004229e-09(12,7,c) + 0.015273785(12,8,c) + 0.083233106(12,8,s) - 0.13274971(12,10,c) + 0.055838355(12,10,s) - 0.027904676(12,12,c) - 0.053948409(12,12,s) - 5.8639928e-10(13,4,c) - 0.063572871(14,0,c) - 0.0091655048(14,2,c) - 0.019331851(14,2,s) + 0.01646178(14,4,c) + 0.068634141(14,4,s) - 0.013970866(14,6,c) - 0.037277016(14,6,s) - 0.1030854(14,8,c) + 0.045489314(14,8,s) + 0.021372293(14,10,c) - 0.073559961(14,10,s) + 0.045624337(14,12,c) + 0.074966927(14,12,s) + 0.097892082(14,14,c) + 0.0057169708(14,14,s) + 9.7795967e-10(15,1,c) + 3.5447635e-10(15,1,s) - 8.9917498e-09(15,3,s) - 0.080143199(16,0,c) + 0.08177001(16,2,c) - 0.020717143(16,2,s) - 6.2864595e-09(16,3,s) - 0.14016948(16,4,c) + 0.064700192(16,4,s) - 0.054473028(16,6,c) - 0.1095053(16,6,s) - 0.021318109(16,8,c) + 0.0071850353(16,8,s) - 0.099567329(16,10,c) - 0.07620251(16,10,s) + 0.065127966(16,12,c) - 0.052821433(16,12,s) + 0.011885013(16,14,c) - 0.072352164(16,14,s) - 0.07836611(16,16,c) + 0.031465557(16,16,s) - 0.094226752(18,0,c) + 0.054347989(18,2,c) - 0.035157864(18,2,s) + 3.4554553e-10(18,3,c) - 0.053891135(18,4,c) + 0.0075232492(18,4,s) - 0.10553402(18,6,c) + 0.17422312(18,6,s) + 0.051354537(18,8,c) - 0.024581266(18,8,s) + 0.014479917(18,10,c) - 0.094779257(18,10,s) - 0.060059459(18,12,c) + 0.025420109(18,12,s) + 0.033749767(18,14,c) + 0.081688841(18,14,s) - 0.00058820534(18,16,c) - 0.075110208(18,16,s) - 0.025438701(18,18,c) - 0.065070013(18,18,s) + 2.6625119e-09(19,4,c) + 0.12246211(20,0,c) + 0.054722097(20,2,c) - 0.067851072(20,2,s) - 0.068904395(20,4,c) - 0.055593685(20,4,s) + 3.6059311e-09(20,5,c) - 0.054784508(20,6,c) - 0.080323483(20,6,s) - 0.064725037(20,8,c) - 0.078047681(20,8,s) + 0.14088247(20,10,c) - 0.094721211(20,10,s) - 0.037935728(20,12,c) + 0.028587188(20,12,s) - 0.068835399(20,14,c) - 0.031688748(20,14,s) + 0.0088283678(20,16,c) - 0.0084234893(20,16,s) - 0.016477903(20,18,c) - 0.044251807(20,18,s) - 0.063523376(20,20,c) - 0.10695428(20,20,s) - 0.046139928(22,0,c) - 0.067700252(22,2,c) + 0.088377478(22,2,s) - 0.074853235(22,4,c) - 0.038618401(22,4,s) + 0.036443079(22,6,c) + 0.034137396(22,6,s) + 0.025494768(22,8,c) - 0.064019969(22,8,s) - 0.094563603(22,10,c) + 0.012952108(22,10,s) + 0.060746465(22,12,c) - 0.033791834(22,12,s) - 0.066521445(22,14,c) - 0.055787309(22,14,s) + 0.0050392453(22,16,c) + 0.0021764389(22,16,s) + 0.060963752(22,18,c) + 0.13460652(22,18,s) + 0.019277576(22,20,c) - 0.086139701(22,20,s) - 0.056567579(22,22,c) + 0.0093068286(22,22,s) - 4.7364357e-10(23,3,c) - 3.2308077e-10(23,5,s) + 1.8922421e-09(23,6,c) - 0.12809933(24,0,c) - 0.043809869(24,2,c) + 0.0206685(24,2,s) - 0.17130851(24,4,c) - 0.013138036(24,4,s) + 0.069899425(24,6,c) - 0.059502885(24,6,s) + 0.028368299(24,8,c) - 0.094453165(24,8,s) + 0.0011214921(24,10,c) + 0.033920184(24,10,s) - 0.049893904(24,12,c) + 0.069888302(24,12,s) + 0.072003815(24,14,c) + 0.087329497(24,14,s) + 0.0023388558(24,16,c) - 0.0024357313(24,16,s) + 0.027070931(24,18,c) + 0.060326034(24,18,s) + 0.028310875(24,20,c) - 0.063858916(24,20,s) - 0.034123725(24,22,c) - 0.055558351(24,22,s) + 0.050543199(24,24,c) + 0.0054402414(24,24,s) - 2.7657768e-09(25,0,c) + 6.306705e-09(25,6,c) + 0.0020309041(26,0,c) - 0.023130929(26,2,c) - 0.044662401(26,2,s) + 0.027302329(26,4,c) + 0.1346307(26,4,s) + 0.11256621(26,6,c) + 0.016202643(26,6,s) + 9.0269449e-09(26,7,c) - 0.069246876(26,8,c) + 0.0032189559(26,8,s) - 0.043630398(26,10,c) + 0.15225255(26,10,s) - 0.03752363(26,12,c) - 0.04679948(26,12,s) + 0.026823544(26,14,c) - 0.060029468(26,14,s) + 0.0065055816(26,16,c) + 0.025496031(26,16,s) - 0.062336717(26,18,c) - 0.13997956(26,18,s) + 0.030013125(26,20,c) - 0.059894202(26,20,s) - 0.0056162312(26,22,c) - 0.01009677(26,22,s) - 0.012220943(26,24,c) + 0.059450203(26,24,s) + 0.011043153(26,26,c) - 0.045339866(26,26,s) + 0.071197922(28,0,c) - 0.096297674(28,2,c) + 0.082894113(28,2,s) - 0.079194524(28,4,c) - 0.013951735(28,4,s) - 0.087454652(28,6,c) + 0.090934086(28,6,s) - 0.032602226(28,8,c) + 0.090758214(28,8,s) + 0.090981632(28,10,c) + 0.052548147(28,10,s) + 0.0615542(28,12,c) + 0.052131725(28,12,s) + 0.010867133(28,14,c) + 0.030762029(28,14,s) + 0.019237819(28,16,c) - 0.076251274(28,16,s) - 0.0096941542(28,18,c) - 0.015568389(28,18,s) + 0.035003807(28,20,c) - 0.086866276(28,20,s) + 0.02830121(28,22,c) + 0.056244029(28,22,s) - 0.017383602(28,24,c) + 0.065758475(28,24,s) + 0.00047508251(28,26,c) - 0.0019505451(28,26,s) + 0.0016195006(28,28,c) + 0.045013381(28,28,s) + 1.1995445e-09(29,0,c) - 5.6839587e-10(29,2,c) - 4.7575109e-09(29,5,s) - 4.4387946e-09(29,6,c) + 2.4200163e-09(29,9,s) + 0.070394557(30,0,c) - 0.030788348(30,2,c) + 0.013466887(30,2,s) + 0.04325475(30,4,c) - 0.016821186(30,4,s) + 0.0089502434(30,6,c) - 0.045927396(30,6,s) + 0.077232006(30,8,c) - 0.043392105(30,8,s) + 0.076068997(30,10,c) - 0.035986402(30,10,s) - 0.0098324779(30,12,c) - 0.034318148(30,12,s) - 0.098709036(30,14,c) + 0.0073843186(30,14,s) - 0.076417372(30,16,c) + 0.01538092(30,16,s) + 0.026097433(30,18,c) + 0.067694747(30,18,s) - 0.059937153(30,20,c) - 0.11843277(30,20,s) + 0.059720235(30,22,c) - 0.0036605267(30,22,s) + 0.049496625(30,24,c) + 0.0098567934(30,24,s) - 0.01104352(30,26,c) + 0.045341292(30,26,s) + 0.0016471945(30,28,c) + 0.045782912(30,28,s)  \\ \hline

 \end{longtable} } 
} 

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am new to this forum. Please let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. That will help others to reproduce your problem and come up with a solution, without everyone having to produce a minimal example of their own.

Comment: I hope the piece of code I added helps.

Comment: Practically it is not usual to create such a look-up table that consists of very long numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to split a table cell across pages. In cases like this a list is the best thing to use.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[30, 2] <long sequence of numbers>
\item[11, 3] <another long sequence>
...
\end{itemize}
```

You can use **enumitem** to modify the aspect of the list. The rules are not necessary (and actually ugly).