# xltabular with a lot of text spanning more than one page causes bad output

Tags: tables, xltabular, overflow

I've readed [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24374/big-table-with-cells-spanning-more-than-one-page) that has been answered 10 years ago about cells spanning more than one page. And I'm wondering if currently there are other solutions.

**EDIT:**

- It is a school assignment, so the format they ask me is the one I have, I couldn't change it even if I wanted to.
- I made changes by rotating the fields with little text
- I added a lorem ipsum because the column that was previously empty in my example usually shows more text even than the column that now causes me a problem
- I added the missing Glossaries.tex file, sorry

```tex
\documentclass[UTF8,12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=2.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Fonts  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\setlist{nosep}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%     Figures     %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Glossaries   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| X | l | X | X | X | X |}
        \hline\Large
        Nombre& \Large Siglas & \Large Logotipo& \Large Objetivo & \Large Sector que regula & \Large Página oficial\\ \endhead \hline
        \endfoot \hline

        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE\acrlong{fide}} & \LARGE\acrshort{fide} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{fide.png} & 
            \begin{justify}
                \textbf{Misión:} Somos una organización que coadyuva a la seguridad energética del país, a la mitigación del impacto ambiental y a la equidad social; proporciona financiamiento, certificación y asistencia técnica; promueve y desarrolla programas y proyectos integrales de: ahorro, conservación y uso eficiente de energía, generación distribuida, cogeneración y aprovechamiento de fuentes renovables para la transición energética.

                Además, desarrollamos investigación aplicada e innovación tecnológica, y difundimos la cultura del ahorro y el uso eficiente de la energía.

                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Financiar programas y proyectos de eficiencia energética –eléctrica y térmica–, cogeneración y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables en industrias, comercios, servicios y vivienda
                    \item Alcanzar una posición competitiva mediante el otorgamiento de un mayor número de financiamientos a tasas más atractivas e implementar sistemas más eficientes de crédito y cobranza
                    \item Diversificar fuentes de ingresos e incrementar la captación de recursos
                    \item Lograr mayor colaboración con empresas públicas, privadas y sociales; organismos empresariales; gobiernos federal, estatal y municipal
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Coadyuvar en el fortalecimiento de la cultura del ahorro y el uso eficiente de la energía en la población
                    \item Incrementar el conocimiento de la sociedad sobre los objetivos del FIDE y los servicios que ofrece
                    \item Ampliar la participación del FIDE como una entidad evaluadora y certificadora de competencias laborales en materia de energía
                    \item Fortalecer al FIDE como entidad de evaluación y certificación de empresas especializadas en servicios energéticos y de acreditación de productos de excelencia en eficiencia energética
                    \item Incursionar en la investigación aplicada y en la innovación tecnológica en ahorro, uso eficiente de la energía y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables
                    \item Ampliar la presencia internacional del FIDE en materia de asistencia técnica, capacitación en eficiencia energética y aprovechamiento de fuentes renovables de energía
                \end{enumerate}

            \end{justify} & 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan egestas magna nec molestie. Etiam efficitur aliquam rhoncus. Mauris ac leo dolor. Nam porta orci justo, vitae pulvinar diam rutrum ac. Duis cursus tellus in erat euismod fringilla. Donec magna urna, vestibulum efficitur facilisis sed, bibendum congue nisl. Mauris sed tempor enim. Curabitur congue mi erat, sit amet pellentesque urna placerat at. Sed fermentum lacinia eros. Donec ante magna, porttitor vulputate mollis ut, porttitor nec leo. Phasellus tempus sem nulla, varius dignissim enim euismod at. Pellentesque quis magna nunc.
Donec tincidunt sollicitudin lorem. Ut bibendum hendrerit erat, eu cursus nisi ullamcorper quis. Ut scelerisque, nibh a ullamcorper placerat, nunc nunc viverra leo, varius aliquet felis ante lacinia justo. Donec nec feugiat turpis. Curabitur volutpat nibh eu risus feugiat consequat. Nunc venenatis hendrerit lacinia. Pellentesque viverra semper risus, id volutpat massa auctor ut. Vestibulum eleifend, nulla aliquam pellentesque mattis, lacus libero consequat dui, vitae congue dui odio vitae nulla. Proin ullamcorper quam sit amet neque rhoncus, in laoreet ipsum consequat. Phasellus consectetur ante vitae purus volutpat egestas. Sed ut laoreet sapien. Ut dictum enim vitae massa malesuada, eget semper dolor aliquam. Vestibulum semper tortor quis augue feugiat, vel convallis sapien imperdiet. Quisque et justo enim.
Nullam eget nibh vestibulum, tristique lorem a, condimentum massa. Phasellus semper, dolor ac pulvinar bibendum, sapien tellus dapibus sapien, id vulputate enim nisi nec nulla. Etiam scelerisque tellus nec nisi lacinia, a volutpat lacus dictum. Mauris sem dui, venenatis id lacus sit amet, fermentum tempus ante. Nulla gravida mattis nulla. Vestibulum bibendum mattis laoreet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
             &
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\url{https://www.fide.org.mx/}}
        \\ \hline
    \end{xltabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Glossaries.tex file

```tex
...
\newacronym{fide}{FIDE}{Fideicomiso para el Ahorro de la Energía Eléctrica}
\newacronym{sen}{SEN}{Sistema Eléctrico Nacional}
\newacronym{mem}{MEM}{Mercado Eléctrico Mayorista}
\newacronym{rnt}{RNT}{Red Nacional de Transmisión}
\newacronym{rgd}{RGD}{Redes Generales de Dsitribución}
...
```

And produces:

[image: Output]

It's possible to divide this cell into 2 pages or I should use that 10 year old not accepted answer ?

Comment: Yes and no.  You can manually split a cell using \vsplit if you know how much space to fill.

Comment: The information that is contained on the page in your screenshot would very easily fit onto a single page if you redesign your table. Would you be willing to do that? Alternatively, I can only agree with the recommendation in the answer to the question you linked to, as a table does not really seem to be the best was to present this kind of information.

Comment: I tried to resize the column sizes (rotating names and stretching other columns) to see if that worked, the text I put on this question is not all the text I wanted to show, so I decided to try both solutions \vsplit and the linked question

Comment: unrelated but `justify` isn't needed here (it is almost never needed) justification is the default. since it's just a list I would split this up and put each item into a separate table row

Comment: are you really sure you _want_ that design? the entire page content is squeezed into about a sixth of the page width and the rest of the page is white space.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `Glossary.tex' not found,,  ! Package cleveref Error: cleveref must be loaded after amsmath!.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is a requirement for this assignment, although I made changes by rotating the fields with little text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split that table with one item per table row rather than an enumerate in a single cell but from the example shown the table layout is not helping at all, as the information is all squeezed into one column.

A nested list allows far more natural reading and takes only half a page (although the line length is rather too long landscape it would look better portrait with this layout)

This preamble generates some package order errors you should fix but....

[image]

```
\documentclass[UTF8,12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=2.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Fonts  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\setlist{nosep}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%     Figures     %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Glossaries   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
 
    \begin{description}
\item[Nombre]  some glossary text %       \acrlong{fide}
\item[Siglas] FIDE% \acrshort{fide}
\item[Logotipo] \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
\item[Objetivo] \mbox{}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Financiar programas y proyectos de eficiencia energética –eléctrica y térmica–, cogeneración y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables en industrias, comercios, servicios y vivienda
                    \item Alcanzar una posición competitiva mediante el otorgamiento de un mayor número de financiamientos a tasas más atractivas e implementar sistemas más eficientes de crédito y cobranza
                    \item Diversificar fuentes de ingresos e incrementar la captación de recursos
                    \item Lograr mayor colaboración con empresas públicas, privadas y sociales; organismos empresariales; gobiernos federal, estatal y municipal
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Coadyuvar en el fortalecimiento de la cultura del ahorro y el uso eficiente de la energía en la población
                    \item Incrementar el conocimiento de la sociedad sobre los objetivos del FIDE y los servicios que ofrece
                    \item Ampliar la participación del FIDE como una entidad evaluadora y certificadora de competencias laborales en materia de energía
                    \item Fortalecer al FIDE como entidad de evaluación y certificación de empresas especializadas en servicios energéticos y de acreditación de productos de excelencia en eficiencia energética
                    \item Incursionar en la investigación aplicada y en la innovación tecnológica en ahorro, uso eficiente de la energía y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables
                    \item Ampliar la presencia internacional del FIDE en materia de asistencia técnica, capacitación en eficiencia energética y aprovechamiento de fuentes renovables de energía
                    \item More and
                    \item more, just more
                    \item text
                \end{enumerate}



\item[Sector que regula] ?
\item[Página oficial] \url{https://www.fide.org.mx/}
    \end{description}


 
    
\end{document}
```

---

I wouldn't use a table layout here but if you must, it fits on a page with room to spare if you distribute the column widths to give more space for the columns with text.

[image]

I used

```
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|
           l| l | l |
           >{\hsize=1.4\hsize\linewidth\hsize}X |
           >{\hsize=.6\hsize} X | 
           l |}
```

so all but two columns are just set their natural width, and the column with the enumeration  is wider than the column with just text paragraphs.

I removed `justify` as it does nothing useful here, I just removed the glossary markup to simplify the exmaple, you would want to put that back.

```
\documentclass[UTF8,12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%   Document configuration   %%%%%%%
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[a3paper, margin=2.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%   Fonts  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%  Other  %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\setlist{nosep}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%     Figures     %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%   Glossaries   %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[toc, acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{Glossary.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| l| l | l | >{\hsize=1.4\hsize\linewidth\hsize}X | >{\hsize=.6\hsize} X | l |}
        \hline\Large
        Nombre& \Large Siglas & \Large Logotipo& \Large Objetivo & \Large Sector que regula & \Large Página oficial\\ \endhead \hline
        \endfoot \hline

        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE some Fide text} & \LARGE FIDE & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} & 
%            \begin{justify}
                \textbf{Misión:} Somos una organización que coadyuva a la seguridad energética del país, a la mitigación del impacto ambiental y a la equidad social; proporciona financiamiento, certificación y asistencia técnica; promueve y desarrolla programas y proyectos integrales de: ahorro, conservación y uso eficiente de energía, generación distribuida, cogeneración y aprovechamiento de fuentes renovables para la transición energética.

                Además, desarrollamos investigación aplicada e innovación tecnológica, y difundimos la cultura del ahorro y el uso eficiente de la energía.

                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Financiar programas y proyectos de eficiencia energética –eléctrica y térmica–, cogeneración y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables en industrias, comercios, servicios y vivienda
                    \item Alcanzar una posición competitiva mediante el otorgamiento de un mayor número de financiamientos a tasas más atractivas e implementar sistemas más eficientes de crédito y cobranza
                    \item Diversificar fuentes de ingresos e incrementar la captación de recursos
                    \item Lograr mayor colaboración con empresas públicas, privadas y sociales; organismos empresariales; gobiernos federal, estatal y municipal
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Incrementar y diversificar los servicios de gestoría y de asesoría técnico–administrativa en la integración de proyectos en materia de energía
                    \item Coadyuvar en el fortalecimiento de la cultura del ahorro y el uso eficiente de la energía en la población
                    \item Incrementar el conocimiento de la sociedad sobre los objetivos del FIDE y los servicios que ofrece
                    \item Ampliar la participación del FIDE como una entidad evaluadora y certificadora de competencias laborales en materia de energía
                    \item Fortalecer al FIDE como entidad de evaluación y certificación de empresas especializadas en servicios energéticos y de acreditación de productos de excelencia en eficiencia energética
                    \item Incursionar en la investigación aplicada y en la innovación tecnológica en ahorro, uso eficiente de la energía y generación distribuida con fuentes renovables
                    \item Ampliar la presencia internacional del FIDE en materia de asistencia técnica, capacitación en eficiencia energética y aprovechamiento de fuentes renovables de energía
                \end{enumerate}

%            \end{justify}
& 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan egestas magna nec molestie. Etiam efficitur aliquam rhoncus. Mauris ac leo dolor. Nam porta orci justo, vitae pulvinar diam rutrum ac. Duis cursus tellus in erat euismod fringilla. Donec magna urna, vestibulum efficitur facilisis sed, bibendum congue nisl. Mauris sed tempor enim. Curabitur congue mi erat, sit amet pellentesque urna placerat at. Sed fermentum lacinia eros. Donec ante magna, porttitor vulputate mollis ut, porttitor nec leo. Phasellus tempus sem nulla, varius dignissim enim euismod at. Pellentesque quis magna nunc.
Donec tincidunt sollicitudin lorem. Ut bibendum hendrerit erat, eu cursus nisi ullamcorper quis. Ut scelerisque, nibh a ullamcorper placerat, nunc nunc viverra leo, varius aliquet felis ante lacinia justo. Donec nec feugiat turpis. Curabitur volutpat nibh eu risus feugiat consequat. Nunc venenatis hendrerit lacinia. Pellentesque viverra semper risus, id volutpat massa auctor ut. Vestibulum eleifend, nulla aliquam pellentesque mattis, lacus libero consequat dui, vitae congue dui odio vitae nulla. Proin ullamcorper quam sit amet neque rhoncus, in laoreet ipsum consequat. Phasellus consectetur ante vitae purus volutpat egestas. Sed ut laoreet sapien. Ut dictum enim vitae massa malesuada, eget semper dolor aliquam. Vestibulum semper tortor quis augue feugiat, vel convallis sapien imperdiet. Quisque et justo enim.
Nullam eget nibh vestibulum, tristique lorem a, condimentum massa. Phasellus semper, dolor ac pulvinar bibendum, sapien tellus dapibus sapien, id vulputate enim nisi nec nulla. Etiam scelerisque tellus nec nisi lacinia, a volutpat lacus dictum. Mauris sem dui, venenatis id lacus sit amet, fermentum tempus ante. Nulla gravida mattis nulla. Vestibulum bibendum mattis laoreet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
             &
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\url{https://www.fide.org.mx/}}
        \\ \hline
    \end{xltabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am very sorry and I am grateful for your answer, I forgot to clarify that the format is mandatory, I made changes to my question. In any case, when I am working on other documents where I present a similar problem and the format is free, I will take your advice very seriously. Thanks

Comment: @EduardoJiménez in that case I would use one item per table row, you don't want a generic cell splitting vsplit solution as that will split mid item that will make things worse

Comment: @EduardoJiménez see update